# Google visualization query data to flask server returns emtpy cols and rows

Tags: flask, google-visualization, response

I am implementing a web application that displays data using flask and google charts. I want to dynamically update my charts without refreshing the web page, so I use google.visualization.Query as follows:

**In the html:**

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query('/get_data');
query.setRefreshInterval(15);
query.send(handleQueryResponse);
```

**In the python flask code:**

```
@app.route('/get_data')
def get_data():
    tqx_param = request.args.get('tqx', '')
    req_id = None
    if 'reqId' in tqx_param:
        req_id = tqx_param.split('reqId:')[1]
    data = {
        'cols': [{'label': 'X', 'type': 'number'}, {'label': 'Y', 'type': 'number'}],
        'rows': [{'c': [{'v': 7}, {'v': 11}]}],
        'reqId': req_id
    }
            
    j = json.dumps(data)
        
    response = Response(j, content_type='application/json', direct_passthrough=False)
    return response
```

The problem is that I don't have anything in cols and rows in the html when I call response.getDataTable().

What do I miss?

Thank you in advance for your help